# nginx how can I avoid the runcloud proxy pass directive if cached files exist to serve

Tags: nginx

I'm using runcloud.io to manage a server. The runcloud nginx config ui allows you to inject /include your config into parts of the whole.

My issue is that I want to try_files (for my cached files) and if they don't exist only then hit the proxy. But the way the config is written I can't see a way to accomplish it.

When I do what's in my example below, the proxy is always hit and never the cache because proxy pass is always included.

Here's an example:

```
location / {

#i can inject config here i.e.
try_files /page-cache/$uri @proxy

#the following file is always included at the end of the block by runcloud and contains proxy_pass 
include /etc/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
}
```

So I solved this like this:

I ended up using IF's and another location block so that I'm only using try_files inside the directory with the cached files. Then using IF's in the main location to check for the existence of caches fils and perform a redirect to the cache location. Rewrites using last inside a location block will stop any further processing of that block and rewrite to the new location, so it surpasses the runcloud proxy include.

Like this:

```
    location /page-cache/ {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
            } 
    location / {
                 set $cache_path "/page-cache"; #uri starts with a /
                set $use_cache 0;
                set $cache_file "";
                if (-f "$document_root$cache_path$uri/index.html") {
                    set $use_cache 1;
                    set $cache_output "HIT";
                    set $cache_file $cache_path$uri/index.html;            
                }
                if (-f "$document_root$cache_path$uri.html") {    
                    set $use_cache 1;
                    set $cache_output "HIT";
                    set $cache_file $cache_path$uri.html;            
                }
                #matching of a variable against a regular expression using the “~” (for case-sensitive matching) and “~*” (for case-insensitive matching)
                if ($http_cookie ~* "x-page-cache" ) {                
                    set $use_cache 0;
                    set $cache_output "bypass cookie";
                }
                if ($use_cache = 1) {
                    #Outside the location block, both break and last behave in the exact manner...no more parsing of rewrite conditions
                    #Nginx internal engine goes to the next phase (searching for location match)
                    #Inside a location block, last flag would do the following...no more parsing of current location context of rewrite conditions
                    #Nginx internal engine starts to look for another location match based on the result of the rewrite result & applies rewrite rule in that location context
                    #https://serverfault.com/questions/131474/nginx-url-rewriting-difference-between-break-and-last
                    rewrite .* $cache_file last;
                }
      
    
                #on runcloud proxy.conf is included in the root location block
                include /etc/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
            }
```

Comment: I'm sorry i cannot offer any support here, but I am actually interested if you solved this? I am in the same boat! Thanks

Comment: Yes, I ended up using IF's and another location block.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code from my solution. I hope it helps. nginx is real headache!